# How to update document Name field using C# CSOM?

Tags: development, document-library, csom

I have a ListItem and would like to set the Name field for a file in a doc library. Researching this question I have seen that you can set an SPListItem name like this

```
SPListItem oListItem = oList.Items[0];
oListItem["Name"] = "xyz";           
oListItem.Update();
```

I am assuming it's different because I am using ListItem and not SPListItem because when I tried to do that in my solution it says the field Name does not exist. What is the right way to do this with ListItem?

```
ListItem listItem = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;
listItem["Name"] = "xyz";
listItem.Update();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field I needed to update was FileLeafRef.

After I implemented that change I was still getting an error message (File Not Found). This was because I was uploading the document to the library and [you can't update the name of a file that was used when it was first uploaded into SharePoint](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8fe8896e-976f-45fb-9c66-2e1717fab7f2/updating-a-file-name-in-a-sharepoint-document-library-through-web-services?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy). I had to add a method to update the file Name after the file was finished uploading, below is the code from that method.

```
item["FileLeafRef"] = fileName;
item.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Interesting, this didn't work for me. In fact, it ended up that the only way to "rename" a document (e.g. its filename) is the `File.MoveTo(...)` method. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26710865/410753